# Can i share my local tape device to server via ssh session ? (backup purpose)

Tags: linux, backup, ssh, debian

Welcome,

I will tell how i'm doing this now (backup).

I have my local computer, and server.

I log into server, and mount my local computer (folder) via sshfs.

Create .rar backup archive direct to sshfs remote folder.

After copy, close my ssh sessions.

And use my streamer to backup files stored by server.

I'm wondering, is there any way to share streamer /dev/st0  via ssh session ?

Any idea how can i start backup direct to (remote) -> root@server/dev/st0

Regards

Answer (score 0):

from server:

`tar -cvf - /dir/to/backup | ssh you@yourmachin "mt -f /dev/st0 rewind;cat >> /dev/st0"`

Comment: Hmmm, look dangerous ? usualy i use<pre>tar -cvpWlf /dev/st0 filetobackup</pre> to perform backup. It will verificate tape after writing.

Comment: You're cobbling together your own solution;  I wouldn't be surprised if wasn't as robust as a designed solution.  Perhaps you could pipe the output of tar through md5sum or some other quality checksum utility and then transmit that to compare.

Comment: @marcell22 With this solution, you can't verify (it's a one-way pipe). Quoting the GNU/tar manual: "Verification requires that the archive be on a back-space-able medium. This means pipes, some cartridge tape drives, and some other devices cannot be verified."

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more robust than what shellholic suggested, you can't use simple SSH and piping. Consider using Amanda, or any number of other network-aware backup applications.